# Iterate inside the sequlize result set

Tags: promise, sequelize.js, hapi.js

I need to iterate over result set from the sequelize result. I have a code that works, but I think something is wrong with it, and it should not be done this way.
I have a feeling this is a blocking code.
This is the code that works:

```
 models.Project.findAll({
            where: {ProjectId: projectId}
        })
        .then(function (projects) {
            //Iteration is here
            var projectList = [];
            projects.forEach(function (res) {
                projectList.push(res.dataValues.PartId);
            });
             //then bulk lookup for the result
            models.Customers.findAll({
                where: {'id': {in: [projectList]}}
            }).then(function (customers) {
                reply(customers).code(200);
            }, function (rejectedPromiseError) {
                reply(rejectedPromiseError).code(401);
            });

            //reply(sameparts).code(200);
        }, function (rejectedPromiseError) {
            reply(rejectedPromiseError).code(401);
        });
```

This iteration parts is done:

```
projects.forEach(function (res) {
                projectList.push(res.dataValues.PartId);
            });
```

And then this code is executed as another query:

```
models.Customers.findAll({
                where: {'id': {in: [projectList]}}
            }).then(function (customers) {
                reply(customers).code(200);
            }, function (rejectedPromiseError) {
                reply(rejectedPromiseError).code(401);
            });
```

How can I rearange it so it uses Promises?

EDIT (Possible solution):
After playing a bit, I believe I have implemented promises.

```
getAll: function (request, reply) {
    var projectId = request.params.projectid;

    var promises = [];
    var post;

    models.SamePart.findAll({
            where: {ProjectId: projectId}
        })
        .then(function (sameparts) {
            //Iteration is here                
            sameparts.forEach(function (res) {
                promises.push(
                    Promise.all([               
                        models.Parts.findAll({where: {id: res.dataValues.PartId}})
                    ]))
            });
            //Bulk lookup for the parts that were marked as identical

            return Promise.all(promises);
        }).then(function (completepartslist) {
        reply(completepartslist).code(200);
    });
```

Is this a correct approach? It seems that completepartslist contains many unwanted objects, including Promise stuff. How can I flatten it, so to avoid complex for loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `.then()`, then you are, in all probability, already using promises.

Your original, working code doesn't appear to be blocking.

Your final `getAll()` looks like it should simplify to :

```
getAll: function (request, reply) {
    models.SamePart.findAll({
        where: { ProjectId: request.params.projectid }
    }).then(function (sameparts) {
        return Promise.all(sameparts.map(function (res) {
            return models.Parts.findAll({ where: { id: res.dataValues.PartId } });
        }));
    }).then(function (completepartslist) {
        reply(completepartslist).code(200);
    });
}
```

However, you need to add error handling back in.

Comment: Thank you for refactoring and confirmation :)

Answer (score 1):

even more simplified

```
getAll: function (request, reply) {
    models.SamePart.findAll({
        where: { ProjectId: request.params.projectid }
    }).reduce(function (completepartslist, sameparts) {
        return models.Parts.findAll({ where: { id: sameparts.PartId } }).
          then(function(res){
            completepartslist.concat(res)
          });
        }), []);
    }).then(function (completepartslist) {
        reply(completepartslist).code(200);
    });
}
```